# Position a section directly below another section with Tachyons CSS

Tags: css, tachyons-css

Using the [Tachyons CSS Toolkit](http://tachyons.io) I would like to move the lightblue (please see codepen example below) area directly under the blue navigation bar.

As fas as I can see the `<h1>` element has a `margin-top: 0.67em` which causes the white area above the theme title.

**Example**
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eedwBE

Comment: And what exactly stops you from adding `h1 {margin-top: 0;}` to CSS?

Comment: OMG... I wasn't seeing the wood for the trees. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add this to your css

```
h1, h2, h3 {
margin: 0;/* the margin you want */
}
```

and see [CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

> > In CSS, selectors are patterns used to select the element(s) you want to style.
>
> Use our CSS Selector Tester to demonstrate the different selectors.
>
> The "CSS" column indicates in which CSS version the property is
>   defined (CSS1, CSS2, or CSS3).

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with default margins on heading elements, which overflow their containers.

Set margins (all, vertical or top) to 0 with Tachyons class "ma0", "mv0" or "mt0".

```
<h1 class="f1 ma0">Theme Title</h1>
```